# Parenthetical double negation?

Tags: grammar, negation, double-negation

Is this a double negation? Is it still grammatically correct? If not, what is a better form?

> He cannot go outside (legally, not physically), because he is under house arrest.

The meaning is that he is limited from going outside in a legal sense, but not in a physical sense.

Comment: Hmm... it does seem odd: "I do not love him (romantically, not platonically) because he is a jerk."

Comment: By the way, it's *under house arrest*, not *on house arrest*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence reads correctly, but a bit clumsily because legally and physically are not bound. By that I mean, the negation makes sense, but I have trouble immediately understanding what you're referring to with "legally, not physically." You might consider:

> He cannot go outside (legally *speaking*, *but* not physically), because he is on house arrest.

Comment: +1 for adding the "speaking" for clarification. I'd actually rephrase the parenthesis as: *(speaking legally, rather than physically)*

Comment: @psm I considered that because I was unsure if legally speaking would technically require a hyphen

Comment: No hyphen necessary :) Usually I'd say "legally speaking" would be slightly better than "speaking legally", but in this case I personally prefer the latter because it seems to bring out the contrast between "legally" and "physically" more clearly...

Answer (score 2):

Because the term *house arrest* already provides a great deal of context, it probably isn't even necessary to include the word *physically*. Perhaps try rephrasing with something like:

> Legally, he is not permitted to go outside because he is on house arrest.

Comment: I feel that this answer is not really answering the question but is simply addressing that particular sentence. It surely is awkward but what, exactly, is wrong with the form?

Comment: It does answer one of the three questions asked: *"What is a better form?"* [Suggested use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Usage) of parenthesis advises that they "contain material that could be omitted without destroying or altering the meaning of a sentence." In this case, however, it seems that author wishes to attach significance to the term *legally*, which proper use would suggest to be moved outside of the parenthesis.

Comment: Ah, yes, true.

Answer (score 1):

In legalese typically *shall not* is used.  It avoids the ambiguity of the word can.  *May not* would also seem to be appropriate.